# C check if two strings are identical

Tags: c, string, winapi

I try to make a clipboard logger.  The idea is that every 5 seconds the program checks of the text on the clipboard is changed; but the problem is that at the beginning the clipboard is shown twice, and after that is shows nothing.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI check()
{
    char *strData;
    char *oldData = "";

for(;;){
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    HANDLE hClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    char *pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
    strData = pchData;
    GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
    CloseClipboard();

    if(strData == oldData)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", strData); //here its print twice and then nothing what is not the intention
        oldData = strData;
    }

    Sleep(5000);
}
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("Your clipboard:\n");

    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, check, NULL, 0, NULL);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: if (strcmp(strData, oldData) == 0), in your code you just comparing pointers to begining of each strings, not strings itself

Comment: You're in danger of crashing here, by continuing to use the pointer returned by `GlobalLock()` after calling `GlobalUnlock()`.  You need to *copy* the returned string somewhere else before unlocking the clipboard.

Comment: I never thought I'd say this after 1995 or so, but this seems like a good use case for [DDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648774.aspx). Rather than using it to communicate, you can get notifications to replace your poll. (And the other comments should solve the actual problem.)

Comment: @lowtech tanks! that works for me

Comment: @cdhowie when does it crash?

Comment: @daanjbrink When you use `strData` after calling `GlobalUnlock()`.  At that point you are using a pointer to system-global data, where that data might change or cease to exist at any moment.  Your program could crash, it could exhibit bizarre behavior (if the data changes while it is reading it) or it could behave as you expect.  These are all possible outcomes at any moment in time.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems...

If you want to keep a string you need to have it static, otherwise the variable is lost at the time you return from that function.

```
DWORD WINAPI check()
{
    char *strData;
    static char *oldData = NULL; // here you'd need static and use NULL by default
```

As mentioned by others, comparing strings is done with strcmp() or alike:

```
    if(strcmp(strData, oldData) == 0)
```

However, now that oldData can be NULL you must verify that it is allocated:

```
    if(oldData && strcmp(strData, oldData) == 0)
```

If a new string is given, then you want to free the old one and replace with the new one:

```
        if(oldData) free(oldData);
        oldData = strdup(strData);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: If `pchData or strData` is used outside of `OpenClipboard(NULL); ... CloseClipboard();`, a copy should be made inside first.

Comment: Indeed, that means the strdup() should be done inside there. Then he can just do `oldData = strData;`.

Comment: Yes.  Many approaches.  I would compare inside `OpenClipboard(NULL); ... CloseClipboard();` and `realloc()` or `strdup()` there on string difference.